# underscore template error: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL

Tags: templates, backbone.js, underscore.js, uncaught-exception

I don't see the issue in this template. Do you?...

```
<div class="wrap-photos">
    <% _.each(photos, function(photo) { %>
        <div class="wrap-photo">
            <span class="wrap-photo-img">
                <img src="<%= photo.get('urlImg') %>/<%= photo.get('photo_file_name') %>" id="<%= photo.get('id') %>" class="photo-img">
            </span>
            <span class="photo-caption"><%= photo.get('caption') %></span>
        </div>
    <% }); %>
</div>
```

Thanks for your help. I'm stuck on this.

Comment: Seems fine to me (http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/nkZeD/). How are you using it? Does the error happen when you compile it or when you use it? What sort of container is the template wrapped in inside the page?

Comment: Syntax looks good - ensure all of those model properties exist on each model (urlImg, photo_file_name & name)

Comment: This error make me think that there is an illegal character in your model's data.

Comment: Yeah it looks Ok to me too, not much there really. Thanks for the ideas guys! I'll double-check the model properties and take a look at the data some. I suppose I should ask: What kind(s) of characters would be "illegal"?

Comment: Sounds more like an invisible character. Try opening the file in some editor and switching between different encodings.

Answer (score 1):

@tsiki: That's a good suggestion. I've seen issues with invisible characters before. You get them sometimes when you cut/paste code from an article. Nasty bugs.

However...

I replaced my underscore-min.js and my backbone-min.js with the full annotated development versions and the error stopped. I can't imagine why this helped, but it did.

Thank you very much for the replies. I *greatly* appreciate your suggestions :-)